# como actualizar la tabla en angular sin necesidad de enrutar a otras urls para que se muestren los nuevos datos

Tags: angular, tablas

estoy realizando un proyecto en angular con backend en asp.netcore y lo que pasa es que cuando registro un dato no se actualiza en la tabla amenos que enrute a otra url o volviendo a cargar la pagina.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi agrego el registro, pero la tabla sigue sin cambios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

amenos que actualice o enrute a otro lado la pagina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo mismo sucede cuando quiero eliminar el registro.

en el ts tengo esta funcion para traer las reservas

```
traerReservas(){
    this.reservaService.get().subscribe(result =>{
      this.reservas = result;
    });
  }
```

y lo llamo en el add

```
add() {
    this.reserva = this.formGroup.value;
    alert('"valores a entrar:"'+this.reserva.fechaFin +" aparte"+ this.reserva.fechaInicio+"<br>"+this.reserva.idHabitacion+" "+this.reserva.idCliente);
    this.reservaService.post(this.reserva).subscribe(p => {
      if (p != null) {
        const messageBox = this.modalService.open(AlertModalComponent)
        messageBox.componentInstance.title = "Resultado Operación";
        messageBox.componentInstance.message = 'Reseerva creada!!! :D';
        this.reserva = p;
      }
    });
    this.traerReservas();
  }
```

tambien intente llamar el metodo que trae las reservas en el ngOnInit() y tambien intente llamar el metodo traerReservas en boton de reservar por medio de un evento (click)="traerReservas()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serviría que mandaras el bloque de código de tu tabla para ver como lo relacionaste.
1: Manda a llamar las reservas en el ngOnInit para que muestres al inicio las que ya registraste.
2: cambia tu codigo:

```
add() {
this.reserva = this.formGroup.value;
alert('"valores a entrar:"'+this.reserva.fechaFin +" aparte"+ this.reserva.fechaInicio+"<br>"+this.reserva.idHabitacion+" "+this.reserva.idCliente);
this.reservaService.post(this.reserva).subscribe(p => {
  if (p != null) {
    const messageBox = this.modalService.open(AlertModalComponent)
    messageBox.componentInstance.title = "Resultado Operación";
    messageBox.componentInstance.message = 'Reseerva creada!!! :D';
    this.reserva = p;
  }
});
this.traerReservas();
```

}

por

```
add() {
this.reserva = this.formGroup.value;
alert('"valores a entrar:"'+this.reserva.fechaFin +" aparte"+ this.reserva.fechaInicio+"<br>"+this.reserva.idHabitacion+" "+this.reserva.idCliente);
this.reservaService.post(this.reserva).subscribe(p => {
  if (p != null) {
    const messageBox = this.modalService.open(AlertModalComponent)
    messageBox.componentInstance.title = "Resultado Operación";
    messageBox.componentInstance.message = 'Reseerva creada!!! :D';
    this.reserva = p;
this.traerReservas();
  }
});
```

}

Lo que pasa es que el post y el get se ejecutan como tareas independientes, y lo que quieres es que si guarda entonces vuelve a traer la lista.
Nota: para no hacer toda la petición podrías hacer si el post es correcto`this.reservas.push(this.reserva)`
3: Cuando quieras eliminar te recomiendo que hacer lo siguiente:
.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="eliminarReserva(index)">Eliminar</button>
```

donde index es el valor numero de la posicion del arreglo de reservas
.ts

```
eliminarReserva(index:number){
   "Aqui haces tu peticion delete".subscribe((resp:any)=>{
   this.reservas.splice(index,1); // lo eliminas si se realizo el delete.
```

});
}

Espero te sirva.